# Dual of a torsion sheaf is zero

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-verification, reference-request

Let $X$ be an integral scheme and $Z \subset X$ a closed subscheme. Suppose $F$ is a coherent sheaf on $X$ s.t. $\operatorname{supp}(F)=Z$. Is it true that sheaf hom $\mathcal{Hom}_X(F, \mathcal{O}_X) = 0$?

This is my attempt to prove this. We can show that $\mathcal{Hom}_X(F, \mathcal{O}_X) = 0$ locally: let $U=\operatorname{Spec}(R) \subset X$ be open affine subset, then $F|_U \cong \tilde{M}$ for some finite $R$-module $M$. Then 
$$
\operatorname{Ass}(\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,R))=\operatorname{Ass}(R) \cap \operatorname{supp}(M),
$$
but $\operatorname{Ass}(R) = \{ (0)\}$ and $M_{(0)}\cong M \otimes Q(R) =0$, thus $\operatorname{Ass}(\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,R)) = \emptyset$ i.e. $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,R)=0$. This is true for any open affine, so $\mathcal{Hom}_X(F, \mathcal{O}_X) = 0$.

It looks like essentially the same argument shows that the dual of a torsion sheaf is zero on any integral scheme. Is this correct?

Comment: This looks good. Once you reduce to modules, you're essentially relying on the fact that since the only zero-divisor in $R$ is $0$, every zero-divisor must be mapped to $0$.